# When i'm adding any markup in zoomin mode of dwg file its misbehaving when stroke width gets into negative value what should i do for it

Tags: autodesk-forge, markup, autodesk

I'm trying to set the stroke width in negative for markups when adding in zoomin of .dwg file it is misbehaving markup grows itself when stroke size gets in negative each time and not displayed as a thin line.

Comment: Could you please provide some code snippets that show what exactly you are doing?

Comment: yes adam , below is the snippet

Comment: var styleAttributes = ['fill-opacity', 'fill-color', 'stroke-width', 'stroke-color', 'stroke-opacity', 'font-family', 'font-size'];
    var nsu = Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.Utils;
    //var strokedasharray = { 'stroke-dasharray': selectedStrokeStyle };
    //var ispdf = document.getElementById('pdfExtractor').value;

    if (markupsCoreInstance != null) {
        var styleObject = nsu.createStyle(styleAttributes, markupsCoreInstance);

Comment: if (markupsCoreInstance.editMode != null) {
            if (markupsCoreInstance.editMode.selectedMarkup != null) {
                var textMarkup = markupsCoreInstance.getMarkup(markupsCoreInstance.editMode.selectedMarkup.id);
                if (textMarkup != null) {

Comment: if (textMarkup.type == "label") {
                        var textLength = textMarkup.currentText.length;
                        textMarkup.setSize(textMarkup.position, parseFloat($("#selectedFontSize").val()) * textLength, textMarkup.size.y);
                    }

Comment: switch (styleType) {
            case 0:
                styleObject["stroke-width"] = parseFloat($("#selectedStrokeWidth").val());
                styleObject["fill-opacity"] = parseFloat($("#selectedFillOpacity").val());
                styleObject["stroke-color"] = selectedStrokeColor;
                styleObject["fill-color"] = selectedFillColor;
                styleObject["font-size"] = parseFloat($("#selectedFontSize").val());
                styleObject["font-family"] = $("#selectedFontFamily").val();
                break; default:
        }

Comment: // Set style up
        markupsCoreInstance.setStyle(styleObject);

        return markupsCoreInstance;

Comment: Could you please place all the code in the question so that it would be formatted and could be read easier?
Also, why do you want to make 'stroke-width' go negative? 
It seems SVG will ignore that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-width
You can test it with https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_myfirst
You can place smaller and smaller values for 'stroke-width' instead: e.g. 0.01